# How to properly require a cron job once per hour?

Tags: apache, cron

I am looking for a command that will execute a php script I point to once per hour.  I tried searching this myself but the articles I read seemed to be old and the code didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a directory called `/etc/cron.hourly`? If so, create a new file inside that folder, containing this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

Then make that file executable.

Comment: If you don't have a folder called `/etc/cron.hourly`, use `crontab -e` to edit your crontab and use the answer provided by @siarhey-uchukhlebau

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
0 * * * * /your/path/to/php /var/www/some/path/script.php
```

or alias (keyword):

```
@hourly /your/path/to/php /var/www/some/path/script.php
```